# Proving two random vectors are following the same distribution using characteristic function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, characteristic-functions, gaussian

Suppose we have two centered Gaussian random vectors $X$ and $Y$ I.I.D.

Find the distribution of $X_a=X\cos(a)+Y\sin(a)$ and $Y_a=-X\sin(a) + Y\cos(a)$ with $a$ being in $[0,2\pi)$.

What I tried to do is write the characteristic function of $X_a$ and prove that it's something obvious (like maybe the same law as $X$).

\begin{align}
\phi_{X_a}(u)&=E[\exp(i\langle u,X\cos(a)+Y\sin(a)\rangle)]\\
&=E[\exp(i\langle u,X\cos(a)\rangle)]\cdot E[\exp(i\langle u,Y\sin(a)\rangle)]
\end{align}

but I got stuck right there and didn't know how to proceed. Any hints?

Comment: Use `\sin`, `\cos`, `\exp` to display them correctly as $\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$.

Comment: Also, enclosing entire equations in `$...$` or `$$...$$` is better than enclosing segments of the equation separately.

Comment: @DMcMor care to show me how to edit the $\phi(_(X_a))$(u) such that the $X_a$ becomes the index?

Comment: Do you want something like this: $\phi_{X_a}(u)$ ?

Comment: @inavda yes that's what I was trying to go for.

Comment: `\phi_{X_a}(u)` should give you what you need.

Comment: @wageeh I made a few more edits, you may want to look at the edit history for future reference.

Comment: By "$a$ being in $[0,2\pi)$", do you mean $a$ is constant or somehow (maybe uniformly) distributed over $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: @Arash, $a$ is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is a constant, then $X_a = X \cos(a) + Y \sin(a)$ is a linear combination of two independent zero-mean Gaussian R.V.s, which is a zero-mean Gaussian R.V. with the variance $\sigma_{X_a}^2 = \cos^2(a) \sigma_X^2 + \sin^2(a) \sigma_Y^2$. The same goes for $Y_a$. If $X,Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $X_a,Y_a\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ too.

Comment: wouldn't that entail that $X$ and $X_a$ have the same characteristic functions? Same for $Y$ and $Y_a$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, yes.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are indeed indentically distributed. How do we get that through the calculation of the characteristic function? I can't seem to find how $\phi_{X_a}$ is equal to $\phi_{X}$.

Comment: If $C$ is the covariance matrix of $X$ and $Y$, then $E\{\exp\{u^T [X\cos(a)] \}\} = E\{\exp\{[\cos(a) u^T] X \}\}=\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(a)u^TCu\}$ 

and 

$E\{\exp\{u^T [Y\sin(a)] \}\} = E\{\exp\{[\sin(a) u^T] Y \}\}=\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(a)u^TCu\}$ 

so, 

$\phi_{X_a}(u) = E\{\exp\{u^T [X\cos(a)] \}\}E\{\exp\{u^T [Y\sin(a)] \}\} = \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}[\sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)]u^TCu\} $

$= \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}u^T C u\} = \phi_X(u)$